# Android EditText getText() in custome list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom list view with EditText in each item. I need to getText() for the EditText.
Here is part of the code :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    detailList2 = db.getAllInventoryItem();

    ViewHolder holder;
    final int _position = position;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_today_sales_list_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemNameTB);
        holder.txt_itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceTB);
        holder.txt_itemQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantityTB);
        holder.txt_plusBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        holder.txt_minusBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minusBtn);
        holder.txt_salesPrice = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        holder.txt_plusBtn.setTag(holder);
        holder.txt_minusBtn.setTag(holder);
        holder.txt_salesPrice.setId(_position);

        convertView.setTag(holder);



    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }



    holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemName());
    holder.txt_itemPrice.setText("RM "+itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemCost());


    holder.txt_salesPrice.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Is it ok if i use setOnFoucsChangeListener or i shall use other listener ?
Please helps . Thanks !

Comment: Why do you even need any listener for the edit text? If a button is click and you need to access the edit text then just call holder.txt_salesPrice.getText().toString();

Comment: This is because i need to fetch the data from the EditText in all list view items.

Comment: I do not understand. If a button is click at row k, you want to get the edit text at row k, right?

Comment: The button above is for another purpose. The situation now is i have a "SAVE" button which it will iterate though all ListView item and get text from EditText after i had clicked the "SAVE" button.

Comment: No you do not need any listener, post all your adapter code so I can write an answer.